# Scheduled tasks run hidden

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I have a few scheduled tasks which run every time my PC boots - one is Process Explorer, the other is Wamp server.

The tray icon for wamp NEVER shows up, while the tray for Process Explorer sometimes doesn't show up.

I can verify they are running in another instance of PE. Both are set to run with the highest privileges, if disabled, they don't start. I tried putting wamp in the Startup folder instead, and it won't run from there either.

Would appreciate some insight.
I'm on W10 v2004

Comment: Are you familiar with Schedule Tasks (maintenance) > Computer>Manage , MSCONFIG or AUTORUNS

Comment: I have no idea what that first thing you said is, but you can assume I'm familiar with most common tools, including the entirety of the sysinternals suite (I did mention Process Explorer after all).